# how to load JSON into hive table?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, hive, consumer

i have a python code with consumes messages from Kafka topic. I want to store these messages into hive table.

```
import ssl
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, TopicPartition
from pyhive import hive

ssl.match_hostname = lambda cert, hostname: True
mytopic='xyz'
mygroupid='ABC'
mytopicpartitions = 10

print("start kafka connection")

consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='xxx:xx', group_id=mygroupid, security_protocol='SSL',s ssl_check_hostname=True, ssl_cafile='xx.pem', ssl_certfile='certificate.pem', ssl_keyfile='key.pem', auto_offset_reset='latest', consumer_timeout_ms=60000)

print("end kafka connection")

# Set topic and partition
topicPartition=[TopicPartition(mytopic, p) for p in range(0,mytopicpartitions)]
consumer.assign(topicPartition)
consumer.seek_to_beginning()

conn = hive.Connection(host="00000", port=1111, username="user",password="pass",auth="CUSTOM")

cursor = conn.cursor()

query=("insert into table sample values('{}')".format(consumer))
cursor.execute(query)
```

error: its loading the object <kafka.consumer.group.KafkaConsumer object at 0x7f88fe848d30>
not the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

The consumer variable isn't a record. You need a for loop to poll data from Kafka. You should also subscribe to the topic, not manually assign partitions to the consumer.

Alternatively, use PyFlink, Pyspark or Kafka Connect to populate Hive, not a plain pyhive connection